# How can you access a remote disk/volume from the terminal in OSX?

Tags: macos, networking, command-line, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

In Dos, you can access a network path easily by doing `\\<server\path` very similar to `c:\path`.

Is there a similar way to do this in OSX Mavericks and above?

Answer (score 1):

Windows & OS X connect to shares differently. If you'd like to work from terminal, you'll need to create a folder and then `mount` the share to it.

```
mkdir /tmp/mnt 
mount -t smbfs smb://admin:password@win/share /tmp/mnt
```

Alternatively, you can click on Finder > Go > Connect to Server then type in the server address. For a CIFS mount, you start with `smb://`. Full details are outlined by [Apple here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1568).

Comment: What if I want to access a whole volume, e.g I need to access`/usr` on a remote Mac - or will this method let me mount anything I want since I am using admin user?

Comment: Any access of a volume, when remote to the system you are on, requires it being shared out on the network as either NFS, SMB, FTP. There's a [handy Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5808814/how-to-share-a-folder-over-your-network-for-beginners) article on it from a while ago. The directors are still similar - go to System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing then select the folder. It's then accessible on your other systems.

Comment: Oh interesting, so the host _has to_ allow it first? The problem I had was I couldn't display `/usr` in that dialog as it's hidden!

Comment: Yes - it's a good security policy to not share it by default :)